# adding input parameter to method makes it stop working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Lets say I have a very simple method in my ViewController that returns a number.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Number: %i",self.returnNumber);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)returnNumber
{
    NSInteger number = 2;
    return number;
}

@end
```

This works just fine, but when I modify the method returnNumber to accept an input parameter like so:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (
                       )
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Number: %i",self.returnNumber:2);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)returnNumber:(NSInteger)insertedNumber
{
    NSInteger number = insertedNumber;
    return number;
}

@end
```

The compiler says:

> Property 'returnNumber' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Is it some kind of bug or did I totally fail to learn how Objective-C methods work?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Number: %i",[self returnNumber:2]);`

Comment: But i put the comment First as compare to All and have answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it some kind of bug or did I totally fail to learn how Objective-C methods work?

The latter. You're confusing message send and property accessor notation. **Property accessor methods can't take any arguments.** What you want instead are:

I. `[self returnNumber:2]`

II. A good Objective-C beginner's guide, with special regards to syntax and properties. [Here's Apple's official material on the subject for a starter.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1)

Comment: That did it. Thank you. You are an awesome person.

Answer (score 1):

Declare method in .h file.

```
-(NSInteger)returnNumber:(NSInteger)insertedNumber;
```

and call the method like this

```
[self returnNumber:2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it in brackets like this

```
[self returnNumber:2]
```

That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Number: %i",[self returnNumber:2]);
```

[try this for more about Methods and Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)

Answer (score 0):

`[self returnNumber:2]` will be the solution. As `self` defines its own `class` or `viewController` and to call a method of the same `class` we call that method using `self`.